# Remove subview from UITableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table, and based on a simple boolean, I add a subview containing an image to the **right side** of the cell using this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if(myArray[indexPath.row]==YES){
    int xpos=self.mainTableView.frame.size.width+self.mainTableView.frame.origin.x-24;
    int ypos=(cell.frame.size.height/2)-(18/2);
    UIImageView *imv=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xpos,ypos, 18, 18)];
    imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"transition-30"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imv];
}
```

If when the value of "myArray[x]" is NO, how can I remove the previously added subview?

I've tried using: `[cell.contentView removeFromSuperview]` but that removes the entire contents of the cell - text included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `removeFromSuperview` on `imv`  --> `[imv removeFromSuperview];`

To get the previously added `imv`, you could set the `tag` property of your `imv` to a constant and get it at the next call with `viewWithTag` (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag%3a))

So before adding the subview:

```
imv.tag = 1;
[cell.contentView addSubview:imv];
```

When deleting the subview you first have to trigger a reload of the desired cell with

```
reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths 
      withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

and then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you do the following if `myArray[indexPath.row] == NO`

```
UIImageView *imv = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
[imv removeFromSuperview];
```

Using the `tag` property is bad practice so consider creating your own `UITableViewCell`
See [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702) for a description how to do that.

Comment: Right - so my question is How do I remove only the image 'imv'?

Comment: With [imv removeFromSuperview] as stated in the first sentence. I added the actual code too for clarity.

Comment: Sorry - I think maybe my question is unclear - Let's say I have 5 rows and populate the table. Row 3 has the image added. At a later time, the myArray value changes to NO. How can I go back to the table and remove the image from the one row? The 'imv' reference is long gone....

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly, but IMO go with a custom UITableViewCell as it is much clearer,

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that - you're suggesting using a custom cell and then simply replacing the entire cell (minus the image) when appropriate? Got it.

Comment: Tried the tag-based suggestion but getting an error - UIImageView does not have the selector 'removeFromSubView'.... should be 'removeFromSuperview' as you originally posted :)

Comment: Ups sorry for the typo - thanks for the hint, it's fixed now.
Yes I could imagine two possible ways with custom cells:  

1. One custom cell which hides the image if it is not desired.  
2. Two custom cells - one with and the other without an image view. In cellForRowAtIndexPath you can then decide what custom cell to use.